# C#, do forms have an option to start with a certain button "selected"?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

This was hard to explain, but say I have a form with a numeric up down. When the form starts, I want the number in the numeric up down to be highlighted meaning you can just press and number without clicking in the box and it will put it in there. How would I go about doing this?


**EDIT:** For some reason, doing .select() on the control with no parameters does select the control which is what I want. But using .select(0, 3) doesn't highlight the default "1" that is in the box. How do I highlight it?

Comment: What's wrong with simply `MyControlIdHere.Focus();`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059512/winforms-application-how-to-set-focus-to-a-control

Comment: @Joey check my edit, is that what you want ?

Answer (score 2):

You can `Focus()` the control and make the `IsDefault` property true to fires when pressing enter or returns (from another controls, as you need).

Comment: I'm not seeing an isdefualt property.

Comment: @Joey You Focus the NumericUpDown and if you want once user set the value to perform some other action (a button one), then you set the IsDefault to true on that other control. Linking events (can help on an input form).

Comment: +1 for isdefault.  very useful thing a lot of people forget about.

Comment: This is not what I want. It selects the control ok, but I want it to highlight the text within the control.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the control's focus in the form's `OnLoad` event.

Comment: Doesn't work.  Focus() only works when the control is visible.  It is not yet visible in OnLoad().  Select() works.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
myNumericUpDown.TabIndex = 0;
myNumericUpDown.Focus();
myNumericUpDown.Select(0, myNumericUpDown.Value.ToString().Length);
```

Or swap out the select with:

```
 myNumericUpDown.Select(0, 99);
```

Just put it in your form load :-)

**EDIT:** 
The control also needs to have TabIndex set to 0 
Just make sure no other control have TabIndex set to 0  :-)

Comment: It works fine for me, but default the value should be "0" .. do you set the value to 1 after selecting ? The select have to be fired after setting the value. @Joey

Comment: yes it's set to one. and I put select after initializecomponenet();

Comment: Ahh when i tested it was the only control i had on the form - please check edit :-) @Joey

Answer (score 0):

You can start by putting focus on the numeric up down, that *should* let you do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call the `Focus()` method to set focus to a specific control.

E.g. in the constructor call `myNumericUpDown.Focus();`

Comment: constructor is too early ... the controls collection has not been initialised yet.

Comment: after InitializeComponent() (when the **Form** starts)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the .Focus() method on the button in your code behind.

Answer (score 0):

During the form load event try something like this ...

yourControl.Focus();

Answer (score 0):

After InitializeComponents() you can call numericUpDown.Focus().

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ActiveControl` property of the form and you should be fine.

`this.ActiveControl = numericUpDown1`

Inorder to get the text selected within the control, add this part

```
numericUpDown1.Select(0, numericUpDown1.Text.Length);
```