# Select textbox on form load in C#

Tags: c#, focus

I need to give the focus to a specific `textbox` when the application is launched.

I'm using this piece of code:

```
private void myForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTextbox.select()
}
```

It actually works. But is this the correct way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Longer answer: just yes.

Comment: configure `tab Order`.

Comment: Why do you think that this could be incorrect?

Comment: @JW웃 the tab order is important as well, but you might want to start with a textbox that isn't "first" in the logical tab order.

Comment: There are various way to archive this. Your solution is one of it. Another approach is configure `tab Order` like @JW웃 said or using jquery. I think which way to use is depend on your hobbies

Comment: I tried, i set `tabIndex` to 0 but it doesn't work.
I add that the textbox is inside a tabPage

Comment: @LorenzoC Order your tab index for all different groups of controls, and for the groups themselves as well, in any way. But to start with input-focus on a specific textbox, regardless of the tab order, you'll need to use `Select` just as you do now. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @LorenzoC, just one thing wrong, `select` should be `Select` :)

Comment: thank you, I thought this could be achieved with focus as a best practice

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
mytextbox.Focus();
```

Or you can set the tab index on that text box to 0.

Comment: Last time I checked, this doesn't actually give input-focus to the textbox. Also, this might pass the feeling that `Focus` is **better** than `Select`, which is wrong.

Comment: "you have to use `Select`, the `Focus` method cannot work yet because the control doesn't become visible until later" http://stackoverflow.com/a/4059620/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter Tab order might not work in this case since it is inside a `TabPage`. I've had this issue before. `Select` is the way to go. Just pointing that out in contrast of the beginning of your linked answer.

Comment: Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors. Instead, application programmers should use the Select method or the ActiveControl property for child controls, or the Activate method for forms.

Comment: Good explanation, but contradicts your answer.

Comment: A control can be selected and receive input focus if all the following are true: the Selectable value of ControlStyles is set to true, it is contained in another control, and all its parent controls are both visible and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox1.Focus() is the best way to select a Textbox in a Windows Forms application.