# Set focus on TextBox in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, textbox

In my program I have a user control that displays data on a window using a content presenter. I would like to simply set the cursor focus on a certain `textBox` in my window at startup.

Usually I would do this through the code-behind of the window, like this: `textBox.Focus();`

However, the `textBox` is defined in the user control, and doesn't seem to work the same way. So far I have tried the same method as above in the user control's code-behind.

Why doesn't this work? How do I set the focus if the `textBox` is defined in a user control?

What I have tried....:

User Control:

```
public UserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, textBox);
}
```

User Control:

```
public UserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox.Focusable = true;
    Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817610/wpf-and-initial-focus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try: `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement`

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(parentElement, textBox)
```

or from the msdn website:

```
textBox.Focusable = true;
Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
```

Note: You can't set focus in a constructor. If you are, UI Elements have not been created at that point. You should set focus during the Loaded event of your control.

Comment: Okay, I was trying to set the focus in the constructor of the User Control. Where exactly is the loaded event of my control(Which would be the `textBox`)?

Comment: I have tried both of these things in the constructor of my user control. Neither had any effect.

Comment: `private void Document_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { textbox.Focusable = true; textbox.Focus();}`

Comment: alright, do I have to attach that to any xaml so that the program will call to it? Edit: NVM, got it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

A little bit late but what it really worked for my was

```
public UserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() => { Keyboard.Focus(TextBox); }),
                               System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
    }
```

Comment: Similar at its core to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9624985/3195477

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the focus in the `Loaded` or `Initialized` event of the `User control`. Eg:

```
private void MyWpfControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Focusable = true;
    Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
}
```

Info: [Loaded event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) or [Initialized event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.initialized.aspx)